# FireFox blocks iframe and doesn't show, while this iframe is a same domain address

Tags: firefox, iframe

I'm now working on a iframe issue but I can't find the problem. I have a iframe in my page and this iframe is point to another page but in same domain. I use angularJS as my framework and using angular router.

My page link is like this: https://xxxx:8443/ctx/#/mypage While the iframe src=/ctx/#/iframepage

This works fine in Chrome and IE edge. But the iframe does not load any resource in Firefox. I inspected the element and find only a blank page is under this iframe :

But when I changed the iframe src to like google.com, the iframe is worked.

By the way I used a self signed Certificate to test https service. this certificate is not trusted.

I don't know why the iframe is not worked, Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a reserved character in a URI.

You need to encode it to `%23`.

Chrome and Edge are wrong, they should consider your iframe's src as `"/ctx/index.html#%2Fiframepage"`, 
where `index.html` is whatever your server sends as default page name, with `"%2Fiframepage"` considered as a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

so your final `src` would be

```
"/ctx/%23/iframepage"
```

Comment: hi, Thank you for your tips. but unfortunately, it doesn't works. if I change '#' to %23, the server respond with a file not found error. Will this # to %23 change make the server regard this request as a file request?

Comment: @user1242158 I am not sure to get it then... Is your directory path like *ctx > # > [mypage, iframepage]* ? How do you set this iframe's src? By the way, if both pages are in same folder, you could simply use a relative path: `<iframe src="iframepage" ...`